# How to publish a nuget prerelease package to a feed?

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, nuget-cli

I am manually pushing nuget packages to Azure Devops feed by running `nuget.exe push` command. When I build my project, the `AssemblyName.1.0.0.nupkg` file is created and I am pushing it as:

```
nuget.exe push -Source URL -ApiKey key ..\AssemblyName.1.0.0.nupkg
```

This works fine and the package is published successfully (as package version 1.0.0). However, I am not able to publish a prerelease package like 1.0.0-beta.

What I tried?

1. I added the following in `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.0.0-beta")]
```

When I build the project, it still generates `AssemblyName.1.0.0.nupkg` but not `AssemblyName.1.0.0-beta.nupkg`.

2. I added the following in `csproj`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PackageVersion>1.0.0-beta</PackageVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Still it generates only `AssemblyName.1.0.0.nupkg`.

What I want?

Could you let me know how to publish a prerelease nuget package like `1.0.0-beta` please?

EDIT:

The project's target framework is `.NET Framework 4.5`.

Comment: I would suggest using the `<Version>` MSBuild property instead of `<PackageVersion>`. That's what I've done consistently and it's fine. (I'd also suggest `1.0.0-beta-1` instead of `1.0.0-beta`, in case you need multiple beta releases, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: If you think there's going to be more than 9 betas, it's best to use `1.0.0-beta.1` to comply with the SemVer2 spec, and therefore NuGet's version sorting :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet @zivkan
I added `<Version>1.0.0-beta.1</Version>` in `csproj` but still only `AssemblyName.1.0.0.nupkg` is generated when I build the project (not `AssemblyName.1.0.0-beta.1.nupkg`). I am using `.NET Framework 4.5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use <Version> element in the project file and it should work!

Comment: I added `<Version>1.0.0-beta.1</Version>` in `csproj` but still only `AssemblyName.1.0.0.nupkg` is generated when I build the project (not `AssemblyName.1.0.0-beta.1.nupkg`). I am using `.NET Framework 4.5`.

Comment: @MAK: And you definitely reran `dotnet pack`? It really should work fine...

Comment: @JonSkeet: I am able to pack and publish the nuget package as follows:
`nuget.exe pack ..\AssemblyName.nuspec -Version 1.0.0-beta.1` and then `nuget.exe push -Source URL -ApiKey az AssemblyName.1.0.0-beta.1.nupkg`
After this, I see the package `1.0.0-beta.1` in VSTS Feed. I am able to do the above without adding `<Version>` tag in `csproj`.

Comment: @MAK: I didn't realize you were using a nuspec file. I strongly suggest using an SDK-style project, and just `dotnet pack`.